# createScreenCaptureIntent doesn't return result

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to deal with the new Android Lollipop MediaProjection API.

I have found that (at least on my stock Samsung Galaxy S4 jfltexx) when I start the intent to get permission to capture the screen (`ProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()`), I won't have a result in `onActivityResult` unless I have checked "Don't ask again" on the preceding try ...

```
private static final int ALLOW_SCREENSHOT_REQ = 102;

{
 ...
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            System.out.println("request permission");
            startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), ALLOW_SCREENSHOT_REQ);
        }
 ...
}
```

And the result handling:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println("RebootActivity.onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ", data)");
}
```

The permission dialog is showing well, but my activity gets hidden and it never goes to `onActivityResult`.

Any idea of what's going wrong?

Comment: Did you get answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this: See Full Example [android-ScreenCapture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "User cancelled");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.user_cancelled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting screen capture");
        mResultCode = resultCode;
        mResultData = data;
        setUpMediaProjection();
        setUpVirtualDisplay();
    }
}
```

Hope it will helps you.